# Putting the number of articles in brackets category blog

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.2

I am creating a blog using joomla 3.2, my menu item type is a category blog. I have set the # Articles in Category to show. What I would like is that the number appears within brackets, like this: "General (1)" instead of just "General 1", where "General" is my subcategory.

Comment: Lovely, have you tried anything yourself to get this working?

Comment: Yes, I've had a look at the blog.php file. Line 101 is about cat-children and that is where I suppose I need to add my code. Precisely where and what is what I have been struggling with, since my php skills are rather limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution!

Here is what you need to do:

create an override of com_content/category and open the blog_children.php. Look for line 47 and change the following

```
<?php echo $child->getNumItems(true); ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo '('; echo $child->getNumItems(true); echo ')'; ?>
```

Comment: Glad to see you got it working. +1 for using a template override ;)

Comment: @Lodder is there another way? I suppose that would have to be changing the core right?

Comment: yes, you could change the core, however this is not recommended. Whenever changing visible thing, template overrides are always recommended